# Place divs next to each other regardless of parent width

Tags: html, css

I want to place divs next to each other. I dont't know number of divs, since this is dynamically created and changed. I would like to have one parent div which will have scrollbar in case there are many child divs (and their width is greater than parent).

Here's the jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/XqSJG/3/). So, basically I would like to have all this three columns, next to each other and with scrollbar on the bottom of parent div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="column">Column</div>
    <div class="column">Column</div>
    <div class="column">Column</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
content {
    width: 100px;
    background- color: #355E95;  
    overflow: visible;
}

.column {
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap` to your parent div.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/XqSJG/14/)**

Comment: I do believe this is the right answer, I think I may of miss read the question thinking he needed more than 1 row

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a content div for the scroll and then a wrapper for the columns, adjusting the width of the wrapper to fit all 3 of your columns (150px in your example).

The column structure is made by floating div's left, but it will float to the width of your parent container, in this case your parent container is only 100px so we need to add a wrapper for them to fit inside.

If you also want a vertical scroll you will need to set a height to your container.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tYnH3/

css:

```
.content {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #355E95;  
    overflow: auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
    width: 150px;
}

.column {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="column">
            Column        
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            Column        
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            Column        
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            Column        
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            Column        
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            Column        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit: made the overflow auto to remove vertical scroll.

Comment: I see, but the problem is that I don't know how many columns I will have. So, sometimes, it could be 3, sometimes 10 of those, and as I see, I need to change content-wrapper's width depending on that. Is there a dynamic solution? I tried 100%, but it doesn't work.

Comment: 100% will adjust it to the parent width, if you are needing it in 3 columns then this will work, if you want 4 columns change the width, the amount of items inside will adjust. If the columns are changing per page how will it know how many columns you are wanting without you changing something? Maybe we could separate it with a class or you could set the width of "content-wrapper" on the page you are wanting say 4 columns on

Comment: Just re-read the question maybe I am confused, are you wanting it in rows and columns or just one row where the columns float next to each other? If so then Danield's answer looks correct

Comment: Yes, I need one row, and columns next to each other. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, and thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdssw/

use `float:left;`

```
.column {
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: yes, but this gives me two columns, next to each other, I would like to have all three, and scrollbar to scroll for divs that are not visible. Is that possible?

Comment: Its because your content width is set to 100px; if it is 100% then we can Place divs next to each. @nedeljko

Comment: Ok, I see. But the thing is, I have fixed width of that parent part, and I want to be able to add divs inside it, and to show scrollbar if width of added divs is greater than parent itself. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jT6SW/1/

```
#wrapper
{
float: left;
height: 150px;
width: 250px;
margin: auto;
border: 1px black solid;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `width:auto;`

```
.content {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #355E95;  
    overflow:scrolling;
    position:fixed;
}

.column {
    width: 50px;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XqSJG/6/